# How do I have to escape the quotation marks in this batch code?

Tags: batch-file

How do I have to escape the quotation marks in this batch code?

I have the following code:

```
echo ""powershell -Executionpolicy Bypass -Command "get-clipboard > C:\File.txt""" > C:\Helptool.cmd
```

This code should generate the file "Helptool.cmd". The content should be as follows:

```
powershell -Executionpolicy Bypass -Command "get-clipboard > C:\File.txt
```

### Where do I have to put ^ characters in the first batch code?

When I run the above code, the contents of the newly created batch file are incorrectly as follows:

```
"" powershell -Executionpolicy Bypass -Command "get-clipboard> C: \ File.txt" ""
```

The two quotes at the beginning and the three quotes at the end are undesirable. I'll get rid of them by escaping. or? Just how do I go about this?

Comment: No need for all the double quotes. Copy this as is, and update your paths.. Note, the filenames and paths are in double quotes to cater for possible whitespace in paths. `echo powershell -Executionpolicy Bypass -Command get-clipboard ^> "C:\File.txt" > "C:\Helptool.cmd"`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any carets, `^`, if you doublequote the entire PowerShell `-Command`:

This version uses the backslash to escape the nested doublequotes:

```sh
@Echo @"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command "Get-Clipboard -Format Text -Raw -TextFormatType UnicodeText > \"C:\File.txt\"" > "C:\Helptool.cmd"
```

If you prefer to use singlequotes in PowerShell, there's nothing to escape:

```sh
@Echo @"%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -Command "Get-Clipboard -Format Text -Raw -TextFormatType UnicodeText > 'C:\File.txt'" > "C:\Helptool.cmd"
```

*Please note, that I have removed your `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter, as it is not needed for running `-Command`s, (only PowerShell `-File`s). The full path to, and extension for, the `powershell` executable, are optional, but recommended, as is the `-NoProfile` parameter. You should open a Windows PowerShell window, and read the output from `Get-Help Get-Clipboard -Full`, to find out what the `-Format`, `Raw`, and `-TextFormatType` parameters do.*